# Read Parquet file in filesystem to on-prem SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parquet

There is a large amount of documentation available on getting data from an parquet file from Azure blob storage to an on-prem MSSQL instance.

E.g. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/external-tables-in-sql-server-2016-or-2017-and-work-with-polybase/ creating an external data source.

```
-- Creating External Data Source  
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE PolybaseDS  
WITH (  
TYPE = HADOOP,  
LOCATION = 'wasbs://parquetcontainer@polybaseexternaldata.blob.core.windows.net', -- Please change with your container and storage account  
CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential)
```

Is there an eqivalent method or way of using external tables to pull data from a parquet file in the local filesystem rather than blob storage?

SSIS/Powershell solutions would also be great, but SSIS doesn't have a built-in parquet connector so that would probably be a slightly-contrived C# script task. As a test I managed to import the data using Power Query, but it's not great for automation.

Comment: SQL Server has no actual functionality for reading Parquet files. The external connector uses the fact that the ability to read these files is built into Azure Storage through HDFS, but this is "smart" access and not just reading the file directly in the engine. There is of course a good monetary reason they're trying to push you towards cloud storage. :P Various tooling approaches suggest themselves for reading files locally (using an ODBC-to-Parquet driver or perhaps Power Automate for Power Query), but tooling recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: SQL Server 2022 supports loading from s3. But nothing from local file system. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-virtualize-parquet-file?view=sql-server-ver16